# Laravel 8 - POST JSON using foreach - API

Tags: laravel

previously, I have created a function to send data and it worked. but the data input method is only one by one.

and I think it's not efficient, then I try to send data in the form of json which will later be saved into the database.

this data uses 2 unique ids which are associated with 2 other tables.

this is my previous code.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
             'nama_event'=>'required',
             'nama_lengkap' => 'required|string',
             'kehadiran'=>'boolean'
          ]);
                
if($validator->fails()){
    return $this->error('Gagal', 500, [$validator->errors()]);       
}

$event = Event::where('nama',$request->nama_event)->get();
$anggota = Anggota::where('nama_lengkap',$request->nama_lengkap)->get();

$presensi = Presensi::create([
    'event_id' => $event[0]->id,
    'anggota_id' => $anggota[0]->id,
    'kehadiran' => $request->kehadiran,
]);
```

and this is my current code

```
$result = [];
$datas = $request->data;
foreach ($datas['data'] as $data) {
    $event = Event::where('nama',$data['nama_event'])->get();
    $anggota = Anggota::where('nama_lengkap',$data['nama_lengkap'])->get();
    $result[] = [
        'event_id'  => $event[0]->id,
        'anggota_id' => $anggota[0]->id,
        'kehadiran' => $data['kehadiran'],
    ];
}

$presensi = Presensi::insert($result);
```

but i got an error like this.

```
"message": "Trying to access array offset on value of type null",
"exception": "ErrorException",
```

this is the JSON format I use

```
{
"data": {
    "data": [
      {
        "nama_event": "event 1",
        "nama_lengkap": "user 1",
        "kehadiran": true
      },
      {
        "nama_event": "event 1",
        "nama_lengkap": "user 2",
        "kehadiran": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and, also I confuse how to deal with validator if using array.
does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated issue that you are facing and i hope that this helps.

There is no need to use `get()` and return collectoin and then access 0th element. Use `first()` that is returing single model instead. So you should try something like :

```
$result = [];
    $datas = $request->data;
    foreach ($datas->data as $data) {
        $event = Event::where('nama',$data->nama_event)->first();
        $anggota = Anggota::where('nama_lengkap',$data->nama_lengkap)->first();
        $kehadiran = $data->kehadiran;
        $result[] =[
            'event_id'  => $event->id,
            'anggota_id' => $anggota->id,
            'kehadiran' => $kehadiran,
        ];
    }
    
$presensi = Presensi::insert($result);
```

Comment: so from that I understand, my code error because ```foreach($datas['data'] as $data)```. am I right?

Comment: That was 1st issue. 2nd one was using $data variable inside array_push assignement. you used $data->kehardian in [], that is not accessible there as well. THat is why i initialized it before and assigned value to it @krystallix